# Create a new File on SD card from uri?

Tags: android, file-io, uri

i am getting multiple uri's from the gellery Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE intent

all i want to do is copy these files to a new location "/sdcard/BACKUP/"
i have been trying for hours without a solution

here is the code:

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = null;

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {

         imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);


         String root =   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
         File createDir = new File(root+"BACKUP"+File.separator);
         if(!createDir.exists()) {
             createDir.mkdir();
         }

         for (Uri uri : imageUris){




        File file = new File(uri.getPath());    
             File newfile = new File(root + "BACKUP" + File.separator + uri.toString() +".jpg" );



             copyFile(file,newfile);


    }


private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
     if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
         return;
     }

     FileChannel source = null;
         FileChannel destination = null;
         source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
         destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
         if (destination != null && source != null) {
             destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
         }
         if (source != null) {
             source.close();
         }
         if (destination != null) {
             destination.close();
         }


 }
```

i am getting a java.io.Filenotfound exception

Comment: added write permission in manifest file?

Comment: log your  newfile, its 100% wrong

Comment: This File createDir = new File(root+"BACKUP"+File.separator); should be File createDir = new File(root+File.separator+"BACKUP");

Comment: root includes the file seperator

Comment: @Raghunandan yes the manifest has the ppermissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission the you can simply do

```
sourceFile.renameTo(destFile);
```

the doc for `renameTo` says

> Renames this file to newPath. This operation is supported for both
>   files and directories

you can find it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was initializing the sourcefile

this is what worked :

```
File file = new File(getPath(uri));

 public String getPath(Uri uri) 
    {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) return null;
        int column_index =             cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String s=cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return s;
    }
```

Thank you everyone for your support